# winform c# a form isnt opening properly

Tags: c#

You can see in the image below whenever I call this form it kind of hangs and I cannot do any function, I can just stop the execution.

[image]

It was working fine few days before, now it isn't. I'm calling this form from a main page and I have other form which are working fine, its just this form which I have a problem, I have tried to redo the form that didn't change a thing.

The code i have used in this form.

```
namespace Voice_based_Transport_enquiry_System
{
public partial class air : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.; AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Enquiry.mdf;Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");

    public air()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        String str = "select * from Air where Air_To = '" + comboBox2.Text + "'and Air_From = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr["Distance"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dr["Arrival"].ToString();

        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void air1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        cl();
        cm();
    }
    public void cl()
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT Air_To from Air";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(dr["Air_To"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();

    }
    public void cm()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT Air_From from Air";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Air_From"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: any additional code in constructor or Load?

Comment: I have these onload :                                                        
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

Comment: what about in Form's constructor?

Comment: i have updated the question with code.

Comment: freeze mainly because you do database operations at the time of Load

Comment: well i have other forms with same operations which works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an exception happening in your `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment out the [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute, eg:

```
//[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()] _
    private void InitializeComponent()
```

Put a breakpoint in the `InitializeComponent` method, run your application and step through the code to see which line fails when instantiating the Form.